# Discord.js turning off unhandled promise rejection on an eventhandler

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

I'm trying to turn off unhandled promise rejection on my discord.js bot that uses an event handler, I've found this online on how to do it, but it doesn't seem to work with my event handler: [solution I've found online](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AvBRz.png).

Here's my event handler:

```
fs.readdir('./events/', (err, files) => {
  files.forEach(file => {
    const eventHandler = require(`./events/${file}`)
    const eventName = file.split('.')[0]

    client.on(eventName, arg => eventHandler(client, arg));
  })
})
```

My event files look something like this:

```
const Discord = require('discord.js');
module.exports = (client) => {
//code
}
```

How would I implement the code in the picture into my event handler?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right now, you aren't handling errors thrown by the discord.js library. You have a handler like:

```js
module.exports = (client) => {
//code
}
```

That means that if the discord.js code throws an error, there is no code to handle the error.

You can use a few techniques to solve the problem. If you're a fan of async/await, you can change your handler to be an async function and use try/catch to handle the errors:

```js
module.exports = async (client) => {
  try {
    // call discord.js code
  } catch (error) {
    // handle rejected promise from discord.js code
  }
}
```

You can also use the non-async/await style of handling errors from chains of promises:

```js
module.exports = async (client) => {
  client.somePromiseIsReturned()
    .then(result => {
      // handle result of discord.js operation
    })
    .catch(error => {
      // handle rejected promise from discord.js code
    };
}
```

The technique the solution you posted uses is to handle all errors the same way, by using console.log to log the error's message. Their code is a concise way of doing that:

```js
somePromiseIsReturned().catch(console.log);
```

is equivalent to:

```js
somePromiseIsReturned().catch(error => console.log(error));
```